# Data type transfering/converting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`a` =

```
array([[0.093949  ],
       [4.71874039],
       [4.72334459],
       [4.8183138 ],
       [4.89309171]])
```

`df['b']` =

```
0    45.1076
1    45.0533
2    44.9566
3    45.0386
4    45.0292
```

How to transfer from **"b"** type representation to **"a"** type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert one column `DataFrame` with `[[]]` to numpy array by [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
b = df[['b']].to_numpy()
#older pandas versions
#b = df[['b']].values
```

Or convert `Series` to array and then create an axis of length one with `[:, None]`:

```
b = df['b'].to_numpy()[:, None]
#older pandas versions
#b = df['b'].values[:, None]
```

---

```
print (b)
[[45.1076]
 [45.0533]
 [44.9566]
 [45.0386]
 [45.0292]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `reshape`, you target is reshape a 1 D array to (n,1)

```
df.b.values.reshape(-1,1)
Out[537]: 
array([[45.1076],
       [45.0533],
       [44.9566],
       [45.0386],
       [45.0292]])
```